# Petri net encoding into PDDL

Tags: dsl, pddl, petri-net

**I am a beginner in PDDL. I am trying to write a domain file for Petri net with a fire transaction function.**

```
(define (domain newpetri)
    (:requirements :strips :typing :fluents)
    (:types place transition)
    (:predicates
        

        (incoming ?p - place ?t - transition)
        (outgoing ?t - transition ?p - place)

    )

    (:functions
    (number-of-tokens ?p)
    )

    (:action fire-transition
        :parameters (?t - transition)
        :preconditions
        (forall
            (?p - place)
            (or (not (incoming ?p ?t))
                (> (number-of-tokens ?p) 0)))
        :effects
        (forall
            (?p - place)
            (when
                (incoming ?p ?t)
                (decrease (number-of-tokens ?p))))
        (forall
            (?p - place)
            (when
                (outgoing ?t ?p)
                (increase (number-of-tokens ?p))))
    )
```

it gives me an error in the following part:

```
        (forall
            (?p - place)
            (or (not (incoming ?p ?t))
                (> (number-of-tokens ?p) 0)))
```

should I define the place and the transition in predicate??
Thanks.

**I already wrote a domain and problem**

```
(define (domain petri)
    (:requirements :strips :typing :fluents)
    (:types
        token place
    )
    (:predicates
        (at ?v - token ?p - place)
        (connected ?v - token ?p1 ?p2 - place)
    )
    (:functions
        (initial-token ?v - token)
        (required-token ?p1 ?p2 - place)
        (total-tokens-used)
    )
    (:action move
        :parameters (?v - token ?from ?to - place)
        :precondition (and (at ?v ?from)
            (connected ?v ?from ?to)
            (>= (initial-token ?v) (required-token ?from ?to)))
        :effect (and (not (at ?v ?from))
            (at ?v ?to)
            (decrease
                (initial-token ?v)
                (required-token ?from ?to))
            (increase
                (total-tokens-used)
                (required-token ?from ?to))

        )
    )
) 


--------------------------------------------------



(define (problem petriproblem)
    (:domain petri)
    (:objects
        token - token
        spring summer fall winter - place
    )
    (:init

        (at token spring)
        (= (initial-token token) 3)
        (connected token spring summer)
        (connected token summer fall)
        (connected token fall winter)
        (connected token winter spring)

        (= (required-token spring summer) 1)
        (= (required-token summer fall) 1)
        (= (required-token fall winter) 1)

        (= (total-tokens-used) 0)

    )
    (:goal
        (at token winter)
    )
    (:metric minimize
        (total-tokens-used)
    )
)
```

I am trying to use the same logic, by replacing the total-tokens-used with number-of-tokens and comparing the number-of-tokens between the incoming and outgoing transitions to determine whether the fire transition condition is valid or not. but I didn't know exactly how to do that.

Comment: I didn't write the problem yet, but for example, I want to do a basic 4-sessions Petri: where the initial state is spring and the goal is winter like that: spring--> summer, summer--> fall, fall--> winter, winter-->spring. the main issue is that I want to do that using numeric fluents,

Comment: I modified the code.